# Joomla 4 OAuth2 code example

Tags: authentication

Is there an example of code working with the OAuth2 class in Joomla (Joomla 4)? How to use this class? I'm trying to use Joomla native way, but don't see any useful example.

Comment: Topical: https://github.com/matware-lab/oauth2 and your JF page: [Joomla OAuth2 code example](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=831&p=3676788) and https://api.joomla.org/framework-1/classes/Joomla.OAuth2.Client.html and https://packagist.org/packages/joomla/oauth2

Comment: Thanks, but you share me a 3d party library. My question is about native Joomla\Oauth2\Client class

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to share some context and hopefully provoke some discussion.